# How to get a dynamic control value placed in placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My requirement is like I need to get the dynamically created radio button value or text placed in the placeholder control and how to arrange the controls vertically, below I have attached the snapshot for your reference, Please help me on this

AspxPage:

```
     <div id="authenticationModes">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhldrAuthModes1" runat="server" >
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAuthModeSave" runat="server" Text="Save Authentication Mode" 
            onclick="btnAuthModeSave_Click" />
</div>
```

Server Side Coding :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
             //...... Database  coding 
             foreach (DataRow authModeObj in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
              {
               RadioButton rdoAuthModeSingleFactor = new RadioButton();
               rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.Text = authModeObj["AuthenticationModes"].ToString();
               string authModeIdVal = authModeObj["AuthenticationModeId"].ToString();
               rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.GroupName = "AuthModes";
               rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.ID = "AuthModeRdoID";
               rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.Attributes.Add("Value", authModeIdVal);
               plhldrAuthModes1.Controls.Add(rdoAuthModeSingleFactor);
    }
}
 protected void btnAuthModeSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //I tried this piece of code but iam getting error

            RadioButton rdo = (RadioButton)plhldrAuthModes1.NamingContainer.FindControl("AuthModeRdoID");
            string authenticationModeCheckedVal = rdo.Text.ToString();
}
```

[image]

Comment: If i execute the above code iam getting error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  at line "string authenticationModeCheckedVal = rdo.Text.ToString();"

Answer (score 0):

This error is ok, because it is expected behaviour.

To solve this error remove these code from pageload and put them in page_init

code to remove

```
foreach (DataRow authModeObj in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
          {
           RadioButton rdoAuthModeSingleFactor = new RadioButton();
           rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.Text = authModeObj["AuthenticationModes"].ToString();
           string authModeIdVal = authModeObj["AuthenticationModeId"].ToString();
           rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.GroupName = "AuthModes";
           rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.ID = "AuthModeRdoID";
           rdoAuthModeSingleFactor.Attributes.Add("Value", authModeIdVal);
           plhldrAuthModes1.Controls.Add(rdoAuthModeSingleFactor);
    }
```

You may ask why i need to do so?? Ans is because the page load is overriding the post back values.

Answer (score 0):

using CSS you can do this easily. Just set the width of the div#authenticationModes as you required. for example

```
<div id="authenticationModes" style="width:120px;">
```

Comment: If we use width for this div the labels and radio buttons wont get arranged properly

Answer (score 0):

Use RadioButtonList declared on page level, here is complete sample code:

```
public partial class DynamicControl : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet ds;
    RadioButtonList rbList;

    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreInit(e);

        //just some demo data..
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add("test");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("AuthenticationModes");
        ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("AuthenticationModeId");
        DataRow r1 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        r1["AuthenticationModes"] = "windows";
        r1["AuthenticationModeId"] = "1";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(r1);
        DataRow r2 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        r2["AuthenticationModes"] = "Forms";
        r2["AuthenticationModeId"] = "2";
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(r2);

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rbList = new RadioButtonList();
        foreach (DataRow authModeObj in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            rbList.Items.Add(new ListItem(
                authModeObj["AuthenticationModes"].ToString(),
                   authModeObj["AuthenticationModeId"].ToString()));
        }
        plhldrAuthModes1.Controls.Add(rbList);
    }

    protected void btnAuthModeSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string authenticationModeCheckedVal = rbList.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```